# How to make it so that on barplot, the value after x>30 is summed

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

In this case I need that all users, who have more than `total_noise_sent > 5` where summed up and I don't understand how should I do it in my code, where I group by or do it in the code of graph

```py
graph_noise = df.groupby(['total_noise_sent','gr']).agg({'uid':'count'})
graph_noise = graph_noise.reset_index()
sb.barplot(x="total_noise_sent", y="uid", hue="gr", data=graph_noise)
plt.show()
```

[image: Plot]

[image: Data]

Answer (score 0):

In your dataframe, you can replace all values exceeding 5 by another one, for example ">5" :

```
graph_noise.loc[graph_noise.total_noise_sent > 5, 'total_noise_sent'] = ">5"
```

to identify them from the other ones and create another column in your barplot. Consider modifying all values of the column to have them as strings.

Comment: alse,can you help me please, how to make divisions by y more frequent so that it is not 0-2000, but 0-100, etc.

Comment: Can you be more precise ? I am not sure to understand the question.

Comment: there are very large divisions in y on the graph, you can make the values ​​​​more frequent, and not 0-2000

Comment: on the y-axis, you can somehow do 0,200,400 and so on, not immediately 0-2000

Comment: Use the plt.yticks() method to do that.

Answer (score 0):

It is usually easier to update the data and then plot with the updated data. First, get the sum of values (for new and old) of uid, then remove the rows which have noise greater than 5. Add the new summed values and plot.

**Sample data**

```
>>> graph_noise
total_noise_sent    gr  uid
0   0   new 20
1   0   old 18
2   1   new 18
3   1   old 20
4   2   new 15
5   2   old 15
6   3   new 12
7   3   old 10
8   5   new 10
9   5   old 12
10  6   new 5
11  6   old 5
12  85  new 1
13  96  old 1
14  106 old 1
15  147 new 1
16  280 new 1
```

**Updated code**

```
## Noise with new - get sum
noise_new = graph_noise[(graph_noise.total_noise_sent > 5) & (graph_noise.gr=='new')].uid.sum()
## Noise with new - get sum
noise_old = graph_noise[(graph_noise.total_noise_sent > 5) & (graph_noise.gr=='old')].uid.sum()
## Remove all values where noise > 5
graph_noise = graph_noise[graph_noise.total_noise_sent <= 5]

## Add new rows for new and old with values
graph_noise.loc[len(graph_noise.index)] = ['>5', 'new', noise_new]
graph_noise.loc[len(graph_noise.index)] = ['>5', 'old', noise_old]
##Plot the graph
sns.barplot(x='total_noise_sent', y='uid',hue='gr',data=graph_noise)
```

**Plot**

[image]

Comment: sais:'>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: That is strange... it works perfectly for me.  Add this line before appending - `graph_noise['total_noise_sent'] = graph_noise['total_noise_sent'].apply(str)` and see if it resolves the issue

Comment: Assuming you got the error in the line where you are trying to add a row, correct?

Comment: If you are getting the error in the line where `noise_new` is assigned, add this line before it - `graph_noise['total_noise_sent'] = graph_noise['total_noise_sent'].apply(int)`